# Compilation error in Apex package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have created one package in oracle apex. While compiling i got an error msg like this..

please help me.

```
create or replace package body "PKG_APP_SECURITY" is
procedure ADD_USER(P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2
)
as
begin
 INSERT INTO P_USERS(username, password)
    VALUES (UPPER (p_username),get_hash(TRIM(p_username), p_password));

COMMIT; 
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK; RAISE;
end ADD_USER;

function VALID_USER(P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2
) return BOOLEAN

as
begin
 VALID_USER2(UPPER(p_username),p_password);
 RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN FALSE;
end VALID_USER;

function GET_HASH(P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
    BEGIN 
    RETURN 
       DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5(input_string => UPPER (p_username) || '/' || UPPER (p_password));
end GET_HASH;

procedure LOGIN(P_FLOW_PAGE IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_SESSION_ID IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2
)
is
begin
-- THIS PROVIDES AUTHENTICATION
     wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login 
       (p_uname => p_uname
          ,p_password => p_password
            ,p_session_id => p_session_id
           ,p_flow_page => p_flow_page || ':' || 1);
end LOGIN;

procedure VALID_USER2(       P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2
      ,P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2
)
as
begin
 SELECT '1'
 INTO v_dummy 
 FROM P_USERS
 WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER (p_username)
 AND password= get_hash (p_username, p_password);

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
   raise_application_error(-20000, 'Invalid username / password.');
end VALID_USER2;

end "PKG_APP_SECURITY";​
```

Comment: What error message do you get?  Give us enough details to help you.

Answer (score 4):

An educated guess.  The most likely source of a compilation error is the call to `VALID_USER2()` in the `VALID_USER()` procedure.  If, as I suspect, `VALID_USER2()` is not declared in the package spec this will hurl a PLS-00313 exception,  "not declared in this scope".

Private functions must be declared before they are invoked.  The alternate is [forward declaration](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#752), but that has always struck me as unnecessary duplication.

---

There are a number of things which are troubling about your implementation.  In ascending order of severity:

1. Those calls to `UPPER()` and `TRIM()` in
   the calls to `GET_HASH()` are
   misplaced.  Just use them in the
   body of `GET_HASH()` itself.
2. The procedure `GET_HASH()` has a
   signature of `(P_PASSWORD IN
   VARCHAR2,P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2)`
   but you always invoke it as
   `get_hash (p_username, p_password)`.
   Of course, being consistently wrong
   means you will get the "right"
   result but it's still an error.
3. The most worrisome thing is that you
   appear to be hand-rolling an
   authentication scheme instead of
   using the built-in [Oracle
   Application Express Account
   Credentials](http://apex.oracle.com/i/doc/sec_auth_preconfig.htm#BABBCIEE).  Why are you doing
   that?